# Live reloading iframe script on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, live, codemirror

I'm setting up some editors with HTML, CSS and JS code. The code of each of them is reloaded in an iframe when it's change. HTML and CSS code reloads perfectly, bus the JS code that is injected inside of a script in the body of the iframe is not working, possible because it's not rerunning once it's updated, but I don't know how to do it...

Any idea?

Here's an example in Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

HTML

```
<div class="result">
  <!-- RESULT -->
  <style id="style"></style>
  <script id="script"></script>
  <script id="jQ" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

  <iframe id="view" class="view"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
    var style = document.getElementById('style');
      var script = document.getElementById('script');
      var jQ = document.getElementById('jQ');

      var view = document.getElementById('view');
      var viewDocument = view.contentDocument || view.contentWindow.document;


        var body = viewDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      var head = viewDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var widgets = [];


        var loadScript = document.createElement('script');
        loadScript.innerHTML = "var $ = parent.$; console.log('loaded');";

    $scope.html = '<div id="test">Testing</div>';
    $scope.js = 'console.log("More test");';


      head.appendChild(jQ);
        head.appendChild(loadScript);
      head.appendChild(style);
        body.appendChild(script);


        $scope.$watch('html', function(nv){
          body.innerHTML = nv;
          body.appendChild(script);
        });

        $scope.$watch('js', function(nv){
          script.innerHTML = nv;
        });});
```

Note: Code seems to run fine when is set by hand

---

SOLVED:

I found a way around. Here's the code in case someone else need it

```
        setTimeout(updatePreview(codeHTML, codeCSS, codeJS), 300);

    function updatePreview(codeHTML, codeCSS, codeJS) {
        var view = document.getElementById('view');
      var viewDocument = view.contentDocument || view.contentWindow.document;

        var codeHTML = (codeHTML === undefined) ? '' : codeHTML;
        var codeCSS = (codeCSS === undefined) ? '' : codeCSS;
        var codeJS = (codeJS === undefined) ? '' : codeJS;

        viewDocument.open();
        viewDocument.write('<style type="text/css">' + codeCSS + '</style>');
        viewDocument.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>');
        viewDocument.write(codeHTML);
        viewDocument.write('<script type="text/javascript">' + codeJS + '</script>');
        viewDocument.close();
    }
```

This is called in $scope.$watch of de editors passing the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b6b39c95ec91f42950957a1ac8dc707f

I see you were able to solve your problem however I have a minor suggestion.

If a user uses setTimeout or setInterval like so...

```
setInterval((function() {
  return $('body').css('background', newGradient())
}), 1000)
```

The problem you have in your code is it will add to the original literation and your setInterval function in this case will be added to the previous one.

Thus a good idea is to create the iframe dynamically and add the code within that. This way you have more control over what's being added to the iFrame and how to handle it.

```
document.querySelector(".preview").innerHTML = ""
var frame = document.createElement("iframe")
frame.setAttribute("id", "preview")
frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts")
document.querySelector(".preview").appendChild(frame)
```